# SQL Server 2012 mail server operation timeout issue

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to send approximately 300 mails from the SQL Server 2012 but when I check `msdb.dbo.sysmail_mailitems` it shows only few mails are sent; others failed with this message:

> The mail could not be sent to the recipients because of the mail server failure. (Sending Mail using Account 3 (2017-06-06T10:59:27). Exception Message: Cannot send mails to mail server. (The operation has timed out.)

What is the default timeout for SQL Server?

Comment: Which Email Service Provider you are using? Check the available limits per day from the Service Provider.

Comment: The email server may have a minimum time between emails sent from an individual account. You may need a delay between sending each email. This would allow some emails to be sent and then it would ignore subsequent requests resulting in a timeout waiting for a response.

Comment: Hi SqlZim What is default timeout? can we increase?